# Transfor List to Nested Dictionary using linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a list that contains data like this

```
ID  |   START_DATE          |   END_DATE                |   Chapter     |   ID_OWNER
1       01/03/2013 05:15:14     01/03/2013 06:20:14         1               1
1       01/03/2013 06:25:33     01/03/2013 06:40:11         2               1
1       01/03/2013 05:15:14     01/03/2013 06:20:15         1               2
1       01/03/2013 06:25:33     01/03/2013 06:40:18         2               2   
2       01/03/2013 05:01:34     01/03/2013 05:30:13         1               3
2       01/03/2013 05:31:20     01/03/2013 06:30:13         2               3
2       01/03/2013 06:32:20     01/03/2013 07:20:01         3               3
1       02/03/2013 05:15:14     01/03/2013 06:20:14         1               1
1       02/03/2013 06:25:33     01/03/2013 06:40:11         2               1
```

I want to create a Dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string,int>
Dictionary<ID, Dictionary<START_DATE.Date, Total of owners>
```

Where the result stay in this way.

```
ID
1
    START_DATE      | TOTAL
    01/03/2013          2
    02/03/2013          1
ID
2
    START_DATE      | TOTAL
    01/03/2013          1
```

Is There a way to do this with linq using C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this with a pair of `GroupBy` and a pair of calls of `ToDictionary`, like this:

```
var res = list
    .GroupBy(v => v.ID)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.GroupBy(v => v.START_DATE.Date)
        .ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Seelct(x => x.ID_OWNER).Distinct().Count())
    );
```

If you would like to also add the total time per day, you can do this:

```
var res = list
    .GroupBy(v => v.ID)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.GroupBy(v => v.START_DATE.Date)
        .ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => new {
             Count = h.Seelct(x => x.ID_OWNER).Distinct().Count())
         ,   TotalTime = h.Sum(h => x.END_DATE-x.START_DATE)
         }
    );
```

Comment: I tried and it dont compile, i get the message for the line g.GroupBy "The name g doesnt exist in the current context"

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento Should compile now.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that doesn't count the number of owners though, just the number of different start dates, which could be different from the number of owners.

Comment: @StanR. I wish I had a data set were I could try it out. Anyway, the latest change should deal with this problem.

Comment: Can i include the Sum of the duration per day in the results?

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento Sure, you can. The structure of the `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<string,int>>` would need to change, if you need additional data included.

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento This should work, although I do not have a setup where I could try it out.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes it worked well, i just want to add the durationin the results.

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento Did you try the second query with the `TotalTime`? Did it wokr?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I didnt yet, but i will try.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The second part dont compile, anyway, i thank you a lot  for your help.